# Help explaining the simplification of an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I am trying to understand the following steps my teacher did in class (from top to bottom). I tried to look up different trigonometric identities but couldn't figure out where the arrival of cosine squared came from, and the other sine values arrived to the right of the plus sign.

Thanks!

> $$ \begin{align}
> \pi &= \frac 1 T \int_0^t F \cos \omega t \frac{F}{|{\underline{z}_m}|} \cos(\omega t - \theta) \ dt \\
> &= \frac{F^2}{T |\underline{z}_m|} \int_0^t \left[
> \cos^2 \omega t \cos \theta + \cos \omega t \sin \omega t \sin \theta
> \right] \ dt
> \end{align}$$

Comment: You can move the constant factors from inside the integral to outside. Then expand $\cos(a+b)$ using the standard trig identity. There's a $\cos^2$ because you have $\cos(a)\cos(a+b)$.

Comment: It will help to note that $$\cos(a-b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)+\sin(a)\sin(b)$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $F$ and $\left| z_m \right|$ are constants, they can come all the way outside the integral.

This leaves you with:

$$
\cos (\omega t) \cos (\omega t - \theta)
$$

as the integrand.

Note the trig identity:
$$ 
    \cos(a - b) = \cos(a) \cos(b) + \sin(a) * \sin(b)
$$
substituting 
$$
    a = \omega t   \qquad and \qquad   b = \theta, 
$$
it follows
$$
    \cos(\omega t - \theta) = \cos(\omega t) \cos(\theta) + \sin(\omega t) \sin(\theta)
$$
From this, it follows:
$$
\cos(\omega t)\cos(\omega t - \theta) = \cos^2(\omega t) \cos(\theta) + \cos(\omega t) \sin(\omega t) \sin(\theta)
$$

which is the integrand on your second line.

Comment: This helps very much thank you!

Comment: Welcome to the Math SE Community! Be sure to use typesetting whenever typing an answer or asking a query. Follow this link : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The cosine angle subtraction identity says that $\cos(a-b)=\cos a\cos b+\sin a\sin  b$ for all $a,b$. What does this tell you for $a=\omega t$, $b=\theta$? Further, $F$ and $z_m$ are (presumably) constant with respect to $t$, so they can be brought out of the integral sign. Can you proceed?

Comment: I can thank you very much! Need to study my trig identities!!

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the sum and difference trig cosine formulas would help:

$$\cos(a\pm b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)\mp\sin(a)\sin(b)$$

This applies here with $\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} \omega t \\ \theta\end{bmatrix}$. Plugging this information into the integrand in your statement gives you the required result.